# How to fix type "unknown" using AxiosError?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm currently trying to create a custom hook for axios, but I'm getting the next error:

> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction<AxiosError<unknown, any> | undefined>'

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const useAxios = (axiosParams: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<AxiosResponse>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<AxiosError>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL;

  useEffect(() => {
    (async (params: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await axios.request(params);
        setResponse(response);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error); //<---- Here is the error
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })(axiosParams);
  }, []);

  return { response, error, loading };
};

export default useAxios;
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I think useEffect depedency needs to incude  axiosParams  i.e }, [axiosParams]);

Comment: try changing `catch(error: AxiosError<unknown>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think error can never be type in typescript.

You should switch between error type after getting it

```
try{
}catch(error){
  if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) setError(error);
  //else doSomethingElse();
}
```

here is a good ressoure for this : https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-strongly-type-try-catch-blocks-in-typescript-4681aff406b9